# chilkat decryptStringENC TypeError: in method 'CkRsa_decryptStringENC'

Tags: python, typeerror, chilkat

I downloaded a trial version for 64-bit Python 2.7: chilkat-9.3.2-python-2.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz. I found a strange problem: when I wrote one method (decrypRSA() as follow) which will decode given RSA encrypted string, it works  only if I call it directly in command line in linux. It will difinitely throw exception when it was called in other method to response an http request. I haven't found any trouble shoot for this issue on website.

```
Here is the exception stack track:

File "/data/api_test.xxx.com/0/v0/share/auth/utils.py", line 301, in decrypRSA
    return rsa.decryptStringENC(encodedText,False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chilkat.py", line 1319, in decryptStringENC
    def decryptStringENC(self, *args): return _chilkat.CkRsa_decryptStringENC(self, *args)

TypeError: in method 'CkRsa_decryptStringENC', argument 2 of type 'char const *'


And here is the definition for decrypRSA() method:


    @staticmethod
    def decrypRSA(encodedText, publicKey):
        print ('Utils.decrypRSA()-parameters: encodeText=%s, public key=%s' % (encodedText, publicKey,))
        rsa = CkRsa()
        success = rsa.UnlockComponent("30-day trial")
        if (success != True):
            logging.info("Utils.decrypRSA(): RSA component unlock failed")
            return ''
        #  Import the public key into the RSA object:
        success = rsa.ImportPublicKey(publicKey)
        if (success != True):
            logging.info("Utils.decrypRSA(): RSA failed to import public key: %s" % rsa.lastErrorText())
            return ''
        rsa.put_EncodingMode("base64")
        rsa.put_LittleEndian(True)
        return rsa.decryptStringENC(encodedText,False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's something internal, or if the encodedText is something you're passing in.  It could be an issue with a unicode string being cast to something other than 'char const *'.  In this case, you could either encode the string, or use a regular ascii string instead of a unicode string.

Saw this: https://github.com/chokkan/simstring/issues/6

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. when a http request comes, the encodedText was passed as an unicode string to decrypRSA() method, not a str type. when I use print type(encodedText), I got the same result. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome - I've been through my fair share of unicode string issues!